Displaying friendly error message when PowerBI service is down
During this summer's Azure Central-Us outage, the app.powerbi.com returned an error message for several hours.

My company wants to display a customer-friendly error message instead of displaying whatever comes from app.powerbi.com when that backend is down.
We use this JavaScript code to embed a Power BI report:
let report = powerbi.embed(embedContainer, config);

// report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
report.off("loaded");

// report.on will add an event handler
report.on("loaded", function () {
    //loadedResolve();
    report.off("loaded");
});

// report.off removes all event handlers for a specific event
report.off("error");

report.on("error", function (event) {
    console.log(event.detail);
});

During the outage, that report.on("error") was not firing for the HTTP error code we were getting from app.powerbi.com.
Furthermore, I looked at the powerbi.js source, and it appears that their code is setting an iFrame to the content received from app.powerbi.com, like that
Embed.prototype.setIframe = function (isLoad, phasedRender, isBootstrap) {
var _this = this;
if (!this.iframe) {
    var iframeContent = document.createElement("iframe");
    var embedUrl = this.config.uniqueId ? (0, util_1.addParamToUrl) 
    (this.config.embedUrl, 'uid', this.config.uniqueId) : this.config.embedUrl;
    iframeContent.style.width = '100%';
    iframeContent.style.height = '100%';
    iframeContent.setAttribute("src", embedUrl);
    iframeContent.setAttribute("scrolling", "no");
    iframeContent.setAttribute("allowfullscreen", "true");
    var node = this.element;
    while (node.firstChild) {
        node.removeChild(node.firstChild);
    }
    node.appendChild(iframeContent);
    this.iframe = node.firstChild;
}

That node.appendChild(iframeContent) was the line responsible for the 502 HTTP error content displayed on our site, but I have no idea how to override it or catch it.
Do you have any suggestions on how to handle HTTP exceptions received from Power BI JavaScript API?
